Why isn't ts.getJSDocTags never returning any items?
Here is my code :
const filename = 'example.ts';
const code = `

/** 
 * @description foobar
 * 
 * @see test
 */
class Foo  {};
`;

const sourceFile = ts.createSourceFile(filename, code, ts.ScriptTarget.ESNext);

const visitNode = (node: ts.Node) => {
  ts.forEachChild(node, visitNode);
  console.log(ts.SyntaxKind[node.kind], node);
  console.log('--', ts.getJSDocTags(node));
  console.log(
    ts.forEachLeadingCommentRange(
      sourceFile.text,
      node.getFullStart(),
      (pos, end, kind) => {
        console.log(sourceFile.text.slice(pos, end));
      }
    )
  );
};

ts.forEachChild(sourceFile, visitNode);

I can't understand why any of the calls to ts.getJSDocTags return items.
Here is a stackblitz repro.

This is valid issue in Typescript.
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42895

JSDocTag related issues:
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+getJSDocTags

@ArtBindu This is an unrelated issue I believe.

There’s this and an example here using the API from the symbol interface.

The solution is quite simple actually. ts.createSourceFile needs the 4th argument setParentNodes?: boolean | undefined to be true.
ts.createSourceFile(filename, code, ts.ScriptTarget.ESNext, true);


I have debug your sample code (stackblitz repro.) and found the issue why it's returning empty array as a result of ts.getJSDocTags(node).
Please check the typescript library: node_modules/typescript/lib/tsc.js.
There is issue.
First check the function getJSDocTags, there we are calling getJSDocTagsWorker function with noCache params value as false.
function getJSDocTags(node) {
  return getJSDocTagsWorker(
    node,
    /*noCache*/
    false
  );
}

Then check function getJSDocTagsWorker.
function getJSDocTagsWorker(node, noCache) {
  var _a;
  if (!canHaveJSDoc(node))
    return emptyArray;
  let tags = (_a = node.jsDoc) == null ? void 0 : _a.jsDocCache;
  if (tags === void 0 || noCache) {
    ... ... ... 
  }
  return tags;
}

Here, tags value is empty array ([]). Because, _a.jsDocCache = node.jsDoc.jsDocCache = [].
Also, noCache value is false
So, it's not entering the 2nd if block (tags === void 0 || noCache) and returning tags value as empty array.
Attached the screen short for reference.


I hope it will help you.

Here is an example on stackblitz.
You need to create a program, and then use the type checker to get the associated symbol from an AST node. From the symbol interface you can then reference a working getJSDocTags implementation.
Given this file.ts:
/**
 *
 * @deprecated
 * test
 *
 * @description foobar
 *
 * @see test
 * @param a some comment
 */
class Foo {}

You can generate documentation for the JSDoc tags like this:
(Say this is file main.ts)
import ts from 'typescript';

const generateDocumentation = (
  fileNames: string[],
  options: ts.CompilerOptions
): void => {
  const program = ts.createProgram(fileNames, options);
  const checker = program.getTypeChecker();

  const visit = (node: ts.Node) => {
    if (ts.isClassDeclaration(node) && node.name) {
      const symbol = checker.getSymbolAtLocation(node.name);

      if (symbol) {
        const jsDocTags = symbol.getJsDocTags();

        jsDocTags.forEach((tag) => {
          console.log('--name--', tag.name);
          console.log('--text--', tag.text);
        });
      }
    }
  };

  for (const sourceFile of program.getSourceFiles()) {
    if (!sourceFile.isDeclarationFile) {
      // Walk the tree to search for classes
      ts.forEachChild(sourceFile, visit);
    }
  }
};

generateDocumentation(['file.ts'], {
  target: ts.ScriptTarget.ESNext,
});

You can test this by doing the following steps:
tsc main.ts -m nodenext
node main.js

Or just use tsx and npm run dev.
